# Count Rows in Neo4j with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, neo4j, count, rows

I am using Neo4j and Codeigniter and I have to check if a certain node already exists before adding it to the DB.

Right now I am doing this:

```
// find the address
$cypher = "MATCH (adr) WHERE adr.ip_address = '".$address."' RETURN count(adr) as c";

$res = $this->neo->execute_query($cypher);

foreach ($res as $r)
{
    $count = $r['c'];
}       

if ($count > 0){
  // ... some action here
}
```

I feel there must be a better way of counting records in a resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @anustart answer and the error message I started digging through the neo4j library and found this solution:

```
  echo $res->count();
```

which does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CI:

```
$res->num_rows();
```

Comment: Are you using a different library for neo4j? In my case this method seems to not exists. I get a:
    Message: Call to undefined method    Everyman\Neo4j\Query\ResultSet::num_rows()